# Android getting response after 403 in HttpClient

Tags: java, android, httpclient, http-status-code-403

I have a code like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(server);

try {
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    params.put("email", email);

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params.toString(), "UTF-8");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        fetchUserData(response);

    saveUserInfo();

    return true;
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.d("Client protocol exception", e.toString());
    return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d`enter code here`("IOEXception", e.toString());
    return false;
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d("JSON exception", e.toString());
    return false;
}
```

And i want to have a response even if I have HTTP 403 Forbidden to get error message

Comment: common issue in HTTP client lib, thanks for asking....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `BasicResponseHandler` only returns your data if a success code (2xx) was returned. However, you can very easily write your own `ResponseHandler` to always return the body of the response as a `String`, e.g.

```
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }
    };
```

Alternatively, you can use the [other overloaded execute method](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29) on `HttpClient` which does not require a `ResponseHandler` and returns you the `HttpResponse` directly. Then call `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())` in the same way.

To get the status code of a response, you can use `HttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` and compare to to one of the static ints in the `HttpStatus` class. E.g. code '403' is `HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN`. You can take particular actions as relevant to your application depending on the status code returned.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [BasicResponseHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.html#handleResponse%28org.apache.http.HttpResponse%29):

> If the response was unsuccessful (>= 300 status code), throws an `HttpResponseException`.

You could catch this type of exception (Note: you are already catching the supertype of this exception `ClientProtocolException`) and you could put some custom logic in that catch block to create / save some response when you encounter an error situation, such as the 403.